# MySQL IN keyword and Zend Framework 2 for update query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I am trying to use the `IN` keyword in MySQL to update across multiple rows. sessionsId is an `array()` of integer ids. I tried imploding them, but it fails with a syntax error because of what Zend adds to the query. Other posts on Stack Overflow use a subquery, but here the IDs aren't coming from another query. How could I accomplish the update using an IN query?

```
    $in = implode($sessionIDs,',');
    $update = new Update();
    $update->table("participantsToSessions");
    $update->set(array("subscribed" => intval($subscribed)));
    $update->where(array("participantId" => $participantId));
    $update->where(array("sessionsIds IN (?)"=> $in));
    //$str = $update->getSqlString();
    $this->tableGateway->updateWith($update);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need implode:

```
$update->where(array('sessionsIds' => $sessionIDs));
```

Comment: Won't that just AND all of them together? That's different than what IN would do.

Comment: You are correct. I swore this just concatenated with "AND" but upon trying it today it does seem to be doing the IN!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$data = array("subscribed" => intval($subscribed));
$predicate = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$this->tableGateway->update($data, $predicate->in('sessionsIds',$sessionIDs)->AND->equalTo("participantId", $participantId));
```